# Android Emulator: Error on Application

Tags: android, emulation

What's the meaning of this problem if the emulator says that **the application NameDB (process com.example.namedb) has stopped unexpectedly**?

thank you!

Comment: lolzzz.. means your app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get message like `the application NameDB (process com.example.namedb) has stopped unexpectedly`, means that your app has crashed due to some exception in your code. To prevent this, figure out the point at which your app is throwing exception. You can do this by inserting breakpoints in your code and debugging it.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html) link on how to debug.